# Spotbugs integration with JDeveloper

Tags: java, jdeveloper, findbugs, spotbugs

I am a build engineer and my development team develops code in Jdeveloper IDE. Is there any way to integrate spotbugs directly in Jdeveloper and find the bugs?

Comment: You need to provide the version of Jdeveloper used.

Comment: Jdeveloper studio 11.1.1.9.0 is theversion we are using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For JDeveloper 12c, you can integrate spotbugs using Maven which is available by default into the IDE (You can also set it up for an 11g version but it's not integrated by default into the IDE) :

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>com.github.spotbugs</groupId>
  <artifactId>spotbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.12</version>
  <dependencies>
    <!-- overwrite dependency on spotbugs if you want to specify the version of spotbugs -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.spotbugs</groupId>
      <artifactId>spotbugs</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.0-beta3</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

For JDeveloper 11g, you can integrate spotbugs using Ant which is available by default into the IDE :

```
<property name="spotbugs.home" value="/export/home/daveho/work/spotbugs" />

<target name="spotbugs" depends="jar">
  <spotbugs home="${spotbugs.home}"
            output="xml"
            outputFile="bcel-sb.xml" >
    <auxClasspath path="${basedir}/lib/Regex.jar" />
    <sourcePath path="${basedir}/src/java" />
    <class location="${basedir}/bin/bcel.jar" />
  </spotbugs>
</target>
```

Read more : https://spotbugs.github.io/

In both case you'll see the newly created spotbug task in the "build" menu inside jdeveloper

Comment: Hi Cedric - We are using 11g. we want to install it locally in every developers machine ,so that they check their code before they check in to repo. where do we need to place the above xml code exactly

Comment: If you are not already using maven, you can use ant and just follow this instruction in your Jdev11g : https://spotbugs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ant.html. I've done it in the past, then you'll see the spotbug ant task right inside the IDE